# Faster way for decimal to binary conversion

Tags: matlab, binary-data

Considering an array of integer numbers:

```
X = [1, 3, 3, 3,2,3 ,1,1,2,3]
```

I want to convert each number to its 4 bit binary equivalent. I have done the following, but the result is not correct. It seems that the MSB and LSB are reversed. I tried using MATLAB's function with `decimal_to_bin =dec2bin(X)` but even this output is wrong.

How can I fix this?

```
X = [1, 3, 3, 3,2,3 ,1,1,2,3];
b = 4;
lookup_table = generate_lookupTable(b);
BinaryX = lookup_table(X,:);



function result = generate_lookupTable(b)

% generate binary code

k = 2^b;
result = zeros(k,b);

for i=1:k
    for j=1:b
        result(i,j) = bitand(uint8(2^(j-1)),uint8(i-1))/uint8(2^(j-1));
    end
end

end
```

The output that I got is `BinaryX`

```
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `dec2bin` you'll see that it takes two arguments. If you call it like `dec2bin(X, 4)` that should produce the desired result.

Comment: The code that you posted doesn't run, so you'll have to improve it a bit if you want help getting it to work

Comment: @beak: I am trying to implement lookup table and the code is meant to generate the look up table. But, the answer returned by the look up table is wrong

Comment: @Trogdor: I have fixed the code and it should run now. Thanks for pointing out the mistake

Comment: So, as @Trogdor said, why not use `dec2bin` to create the lookup table?

Comment: For 10 elements it is okay to use dec2bin, but for 1 million elements, I thought a look up table based approach would be faster. Also, I find that `dec2bin()` is slower and may not work well for b > 32 (machine precision) . I want to apply the conversion process to images which take lot of time if i do `dec2bin()`

Comment: ^^ "`dec2bin` to create the lookup table"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think beaker means something along these lines:

```
% Your vector
X = [1, 3, 3, 3,2,3 ,1,1,2,3];

% number of bits to use 
numbits = 4;

% Create lookup table
little_endian = true;

LUT = dec2bin(0:15, numbits) == '1';
if ~little_endian
    LUT = fliplr(LUT); end

% The conversion 
bits = LUT(X(:) + 1, :)
```

Alternatively, you can do what `dec2bin` does, but without all the fuss around it:

```
bits = (rem(floor(X(:)*pow2(1-numbits:0)),2) == 1);
```

Comment: `dec2bin` produces a char array, so `LUT = LUT - '0'` might be necessary. Alternatively, if the OP has the Communications Toolbox, they can use `de2bi` which gives numerical values (watch the endian-ness).

Comment: @beaker even if that is true, I still prefer to answer using only built-in MATLAB functions -- not every googler coming by here will have that toolbox. Also, I deliberately converted to `logical` instead of `char`, because well, that just makes more sense :) The OP also posted a table in `uint8`, not `char`, so I chose `logical` because it's numeric and has the added benefit of being either `0` or `1`, not `255` or `A` or something silly like that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where you're casting the results of `dec2bin` to logical. I agree about `de2bi`, it's just an alternative.

Comment: @beaker oh whoops, you're right, I had that in my draft but not in the post. Editing...

Comment: @SrishtiM ...works over here. Can you give an example?

Comment: The 1 needs to be in quotes: `LUT = dec2bin(0:15, numbits) == '1';` that makes this an excellent solution

Comment: @Trogdor OMFG, edited w/o thinking...I guess it's not my day today :) Editing again, thanks.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, np, its a great solution now that the typos are fixed :)